# display a file through java script

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Is there a way to display a file having a `.php` extn in html using javacript on a click event as any files which are supposed to be displayed on different clicks ?

Comment: you can try an an ajax call and $('div').html() to disply it

Comment: You can also try the above but without jQuery. It's not needed for XHR and basic DOM manipulation @user3510665.

Comment: ya Thank You @SamHH ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by jquery which is fairly simpler method

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").load("your file url");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"></div>

<button>load file</button>

</body>
</html>
```